# How can I attach VS Code to a node process running in a docker container

Tags: node.js, docker, visual-studio-code, docker-compose

I'm trying to attach the Visual Studio Code debugger to a node.js app that is running inside a Docker container.

I start the app like:

```
node --debug-brk app.js
```

I expose the debugger port in `docker-compose.yml`:

```
app:
  build: .
  working_dir: /code
  volumes:
    - .:/code
  command: npm run debug
  ports:
    - "3004:3000"
    - "5858:5858"
```

My `launch.json` looks like:

```
{
    "version": "0.1.0",
    "configurations": [
        {
            "name": "Attach",
            "type": "node",
            "address": "localhost",
            "port": 5858
        }
    ]
}
```

Now, when I start the application and attach the debugger this will correctly connect (I can see the values flashing in the debugger UI already), but then it will stop, telling me the following:

```
Error opening 'app.js' (File not found: /code/app.js).
```

This is due to the fact that docker will not mount the app in root but in `/code` (see `volumes` in `docker-compose.yml`) and VS code is confused by the sudden offset.

When I run the application outside the container (i.e. locally, without offset) it works just as expected and I can use the debugger as expected.

There seems to be a `cwd` option for the launch configuration but I am not sure if that makes any difference in my case.

Can I fix this path offset? Am I missing something else here?

Comment: Would a symlink from `/code > /code/dir/on/your/host` work?

Comment: @ChrisMcKinnel So this is weird. When I create the symlink I will not see the error message anymore, the debugger will opern the correct file and stop at the correct line but after something around 2 seconds it disappears again just like described in the OP. Pretty weird.

Comment: Disappears as in you get the same error as above?

Comment: @ChrisMcKinnel Disappears as in no error, no debugging. Smells buggy to me.

Comment: Hrrmmmm, try and `strace -p [pid]` of the debugger (if you can do it fast enough) and see if it spits out any errors when it dies?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This feature is now officially supported by VSCode: https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode-node-debug/issues/8

Answer (score 0):

I think your debugger is being tricked because your app path inside docker is `/code` and on your computer it is something different.

Maybe something like `/home/m90/code`.

So when your debugger tries to look at your code on your local machine. It looks at `/code` which exists only inside of docker. This path makes no sense outside of docker.

If you could tell your debugger to look for you code at the correct place on your machine (again outside of the docker container) that would fixed it.

Another way would be to have the same path for your code inside and outside of docker.

Comment: This path offset is more or less what is stated in my question, I'll try to make that clearer though. Trouble is docker won't mount root directories so there will *always* be an offset in the scenario described.

Comment: what I meant is inside your docker compose yml. Adjust your volumes with something like: `- /home/m90/code:/home/m90/code` and your workdir with `working_dir: /home/m90/code` (of course adjusting it with the path where your code is located on your computer).

Answer (score 0):

Try this modified version of docker-compose.yml. (with copy /code directory in docker to your host directory /code)

`docker-compose.yml`

```
app:
  build: .
  working_dir: /code
  volumes:
    - /code:/code
  command: npm run debug
  ports:
    - "3004:3000"
    - "5858:5858"
```

only changed one line: **`/code:/code`** instead of `.:/code`

Answer (score 0):

You could try bind-mounting your current directory on `/code` so that VS can find your source code there: `sudo mount --bind . /code`

Comment: Same issue unfortunately

Answer (score 0):

For me it didn't work until I used inspect: `node --inspect=5858 app.js`