# Launching node docker container for debugging from VS Code

Tags: node.js, docker, visual-studio-code

VS Code uses a locally installed version of node for debugging. My question is whether it is possible to use node in a docker container instead.

I've found several references on doing something like this with the remote debugging approach vscode offers. [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33032164/how-can-i-attach-vs-code-to-a-node-process-running-in-a-docker-container) seems to be pretty close to what I'm looking for. However, I don't want to start the container externally.

My example is the simple hello world from [vscode docs](https://code.visualstudio.com/Docs/runtimes/nodejs). I really would love to simply press the launch button and start debugging in it without having a locally installed version of node.

Comment: Just came across vscode tasks. This seems to be what I'm looking for. However, it doesn't seem to be able to start a docker container. Will have to further explorer on this.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not aware of any way to launch the container from the debugger in Visual Studio Code. However, for [Visual Studio Community](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/products/visual-studio-community-vs.aspx), there is the [Docker Tools for Visual Studio](https://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/0f5b2caa-ea00-41c8-b8a2-058c7da0b3e4) plugin.

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at this one, I think it is what you are looking for:
https://alexanderzeitler.com/articles/debugging-a-nodejs-es6-application-in-a-docker-container-using-visual-studio-code/

Comment: I know this excellent article which is indeed one possible solution. However, I was wondering whether it is possible to have this all running in one transaction. The way via remote debugging explained by Alexander requires to start the container (e.g. via the command line) and then attach the debugger. It would be great to tell vscode that it has to launch the container itself. Then it would be possible to simply click start and immediately debug.